How to specify management.metrics.web.server.request.autotime.enabled as false with Spring Boot 3.2.x?
With Spring Boot 3.x the Property management.metrics.web.server.request.autotime.enabled has been deprecated and is not supported. The Changelog states it "[s]hould be applied at the ObservationRegistry level.", but does not provide an example or directions on how to adapt to the change.
What does this exactly mean? How would you go about setting this property to false?
I have tried looking for non-invasive solutions that would not require adding new monitoring code, but have found none.
